# Changing Job with blue card after 18 months

Tags: germany, working-visas, eu, blue-card

I have a blue card in Germany and I am holding it for 18 months. I am changing my employer. Do I still need to have permission from the authority? My new job is in a different city. If I have to inform the authority then Is it better to move on to the new city and ask the authority? Or it will take more time there?

Comment: You can do it after 24 months. Then you dont need to inform authorities. Before 24 months, you have to inform you Ausländerbehörde.

Comment: I have to change my city very fast. I know I have to do it where I am registered. I have applied where I am living now but it is taking way too much time due to COVID situation. Do you think if I change my city only with my contract and other documents it can be changed or they can only do once they have complete file from my Ausländerbehörde